# PHP UBB remover regex produces error

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to fix a bug in someone's news system, it uses UBB to allow the editors some sort of flexiblity. So for example to allow **bold** text the following regex is used:

```
$message = preg_replace('_\[b\](.*?)\[/b\]_ise', "bold('\\1')", $message);
```

This works fine. However, there is also a function to strip the UBB code for displaying on the front page, which is as follows:

```
$message = preg_replace('_\[b\](.*?)\[/b\]_ise', "\\1", $message);
```

And this regex produces an error, which does not make any sense to me, after all it is the exact same regex.

```
Fatal error: preg_replace() [<a href='function.preg-replace'>function.preg-replace</a>]: Failed evaluating code: This is bold in /public_html/functions.inc.php on line 122

121 $message = preg_replace('_\[i\](.*?)\[/i\]_ise', "\\1", $message);
122 $message = preg_replace('_\[b\](.*?)\[/b\]_ise', "\\1", $message);
123 $message = preg_replace('_\[u\](.*?)\[/u\]_ise', "\\1", $message);
```

Comment: The `e` suffix on preg_replace evaluates the code that's generated from the regex as PHP; can you add to your question an example of the input that's failing? At a guess, I'd say that if you changed the suffix to `is`, it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use:

```
$message = preg_replace('_\[b\](.*?)\[/b\]_is', "bold('\\1')", $message);
```

and

```
$message = preg_replace('_\[b\](.*?)\[/b\]_is', "\\1", $message);
```

Comment: Working, do you have an explanation for this?

Comment: Modifier `e` is for evaluation of the replacement, which means PHP execute `\\1` as a code. You want `\\1` to be a text string, not a PHP code... *(Note:* `\\1` *represents* `(.*?)` *in the regex search pattern)*

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much for the explanation! The original developer probably just blind copied the code...